# How to map this yml to Java Map?

Tags: java, spring, yaml, spring-cloud-config

I would like to map the following part of our application yml to be converted into  Java HashMap. I tried but the map contains 0 elements. Here is the code

```
transmission-services :
  business-process-list :
     BIB863 :
        transactions :
          transactionCodes:
            - CHANGE
          transactionTypes:
            - BISTUPC
          writeToObtSuspTmpTable: true
     BIB971 :
       transactions :
         transactionCodes:
           - ADD
         transactionTypes:
           - BISTVENDR
         writeToObtSuspTmpTable: true


@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class TransactionConfiguration {
    private List<String> transactionCodes;
    private String transactionTypes;
    private boolean writeToObtSuspTmpTable;
}

@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "transmission-services")
@Component
@Getter
@Setter
public class UpcServicesConfiguration {
    private Map<String, TransactionConfiguration> businessProcesses
            = new HashMap<>();
}
```

in the above yml I want BIB863 and BIB971 as keys for the map and TransactionConfiguration as value in the map.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/config")
public class ConfigurationTestController {
    @Autowired
    private UpcServicesConfiguration upcServicesConfiguration;

    @GetMapping(value = "test")
    public ResponseEntity<String> getUpcConfig() {
        StringBuilder conf = new StringBuilder();
        for(Map.Entry<String, TransactionConfiguration> entry:upcServicesConfiguration.getBusinessProcesses().entrySet()) {
            conf.append("Key="+entry.getKey());
            conf.append(", value="+entry.getValue());
        }
        return new ResponseEntity(conf.toString(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Above rest endpoint returns empty string and not what I expected it to return. Can someone explain what is wrong here?

Comment: Did you try using `@EnableConfigurationProperties`?

Comment: I tried but no luck